# In React / Redux, if a function component is dispatching a function using redux-thunk, how can it setIsLoading()?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I think the reason we use redux-thunk is so that we can dispatch a function when we define `mapDispatchToProps()`. (Usually, by having `actionCreator()` returning a function)

But, assuming we are using a function component, when we dispatch a function to load data, there seems to be no way to use the `setIsLoading()` which comes from

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
```

because `setIsLoading` is inside the function component and you can't use it in `mapDispatchToProps()`?

It seems one way is to use

```
<button onClick={() => {setIsLoading(true); props.dispatchGetData(setIsLoading)}}>
```

which is first `setIsLoading(true)` and pass the `setIsLoading` to `dispatchGetData()` so that later on, it can call `setIsLoading(false)` when data is received or failed to received.

Is this a proper way or what is a proper way?  It seems we can also use `useEffect()` and we can directly do the `fetch()` and won't dispatch any function and therefore, not using redux-thunk?

Comment: The official async example keeps loading values in the store and updates them based on specific actions in the reducer: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/reducers/index.js

Comment: the way it is written is different from what I have thought... when user chooses a topic, I would have dispatched a function that does a `fetch().then().then(data => dispatch({ type: "GOT_DATA", data: data})`  right now it is just dispatching a state for the topic and let `componentDidUpdate()` handle the `fetch()`... I wonder if my way is not recommended...

Comment: I'm not saying your way is not recommended. Depending on your needs, it may help to have loading available from the store to use outside this immediate component.

Comment: hm... actually if I read carefully into that example code, it is like a spaghetti of states... so many conditions, and so many lines of code, just to choose one out of two reddit topics and show the list

Answer (score 0):

You can `useEffect` and check if the data come back to the component has changed.

Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    setIsLoading(false);
}, [props.data])
```

Comment: what about the part setting it to true?

Comment: You set it when you click the button, right?

`<button onClick={() => {setIsLoading(true); props.dispatchGetData(setIsLoading)}}>`